# How to add multiple Dynamic Power Queries into one spreadsheet excel

Tags: excel, refresh, powerquery

Is it possible to insert multiple dynamic power queries, one on top of the other, into a single excel spreadsheet and have the queries refresh when new data has been added to the tables?

I have six different dynamic power queries from six different tables.

When I put each query into their own spreadsheet by themselves they work perfectly. When I add additional data to the table and refresh the query the new data is added to the query worksheet.

However, when I place all six queries into one worksheet one on top of the other, the new data added to the tables will not refresh.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Using Excel 365 on Windows 10

Comment: It's possible it's by design to avoid overwriting tables. What about positioning them side by side?

Comment: That is what I suspected. Thank you for confirming. I can't place them side by side, there are too many columns. I need to be able to save them in PDF format with them appearing on the pages consecutively. I and not a superuser and wonder if there is another way to do it, maybe with VBA, but I would not even have any idea what to search for, if you have any suggestions I am open. Thanks!

Comment: Arrange side by side. Select the `Page Layout` tab on the ribbon and click on `Print Titles`. In the `Rows to Repeat at Top`, click the arrow and select your heading rows. If your tables are all aligned at the top, you should be able to print what you want. You might need to modify page breaks in`View` tab, `Page break preview`.

Comment: If they have to be stacked, and if they have the same format, perhaps append all of them together, then load that one.  You cant stack them and have them move by themselves as more rows get added

Comment: I am not sure what was up with my workbook. I started over with a blank workbook and as long as all tables have the same number of columns they refresh fine. I have 8 queries on one page and they all refresh fine.  I wanted to post this update if someone else runs into this problem, I don't want them to think that it can't be done.